# how to copy table from one server to another in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to find a way to copy data from one table in SQL Server 2008 to another table in SQL Server 2005. I want to perform this on a daily basis.

Comment: both Data and Structure...on sql server 2008 , the data will be entered daily by the employees and in the morning i need to transfer these datas to sql server 2005 for BI reports...

Comment: the table contains only 2000 rows..nope i cant delete /recreate the table..i need to do it in 2 different servers..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created a linked server, than you can retrieve data from linked server and
insert to source . Than you create a job that will do it .

You can right click on database and then click import/export (SSIS) . SQL will create a package,that you can view as a script and to run it as job

Answer (score 2):

You want to look at Sql Server Integration Services (SSIS). This is what is provided with SQL Server to allow you to move data into/out of/around SQL Server and other data formats. It can be scheduled. This is a very simple way of moving data between different servewrs and platforms.

There is a simple wizard available in Management Studio. In the object explorer, right click the required database and choose 'Tasks>Import Data' if you are on the destination server, or 'Tasks>Export Data' if you are on the source server.

James :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a linked server you can write this T-SQL on the targeted server under targeted database:

```
select * into srctabl from [link server].srcdb.srctable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Replication service.

[SQL Server 2008 Replication: High Availability Solution Part One – by Abi Chapagai](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/databaseexpertisecom/archive/2010/07/28/sql-server-2008-replication_3A00_--high-availability-solution-part-one-_1320_-by-abi-chapagai.aspx)

Comment: This link is dead now (03-29-2022)